# Next.JS getStaticProps Not Working As Expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to create a website that shows dynamically updating feedbacks as cards. My `fetchData` variable in `Home` function always returns `undefined`. Code I tried is:

```
import UserCard from "../components/usercard"
import type { InferGetStaticPropsType, GetStaticProps } from 'next'

type FeedbackData = {
  feedbackId: number
  feedback: string
  playerName: string
  userId: number
  rating: number
}


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<{fetchData: FeedbackData[]}> = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/all")
  const fetchData = await response.json()

  return {
    props: {
      fetchData,
    },
  };
}

function Home({ fetchData }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
  fetchData = fetchData ?? []
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-center my-8">Feedbacks</h1>
      <ul className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 p-6">
        {fetchData.map((data: FeedbackData) => (
          <UserCard
            key={data.feedbackId}
            feedback={data.feedback}
            userId={data.userId}
            playerName={data.playerName}
            feedbackId={data.feedbackId}
            rating={data.rating}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

My api's json response is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "6496e2e77cc2d26e513ea75a",
    "feedbackId": 129942,
    "feedback": "Feedback Test",
    "playerName": "ItsTuna_YT",
    "userId": 3522406346,
    "rating": 10
  },
  {
    "id": "6496ea491749221e0d96cbd5",
    "feedbackId": 810122,
    "feedback": "Feedback Test",
    "playerName": "ItsTuna_YT",
    "userId": 3522406346,
    "rating": 10
  },
  {
    "id": "6496ea5c1749221e0d96cbd7",
    "feedbackId": 214093,
    "feedback": "Feedback Test",
    "playerName": "ItsTuna_YT",
    "userId": 3522406346,
    "rating": 10
  }
]
```

Comment: can you run the fetching logic in `try/catch` to see if there is any error. if no errror, `console.log(fetchData)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is missing `getStaticPaths`. You need it in order to tell Nextjs which pages to render using the `getStaticProps`. Unless you are not using dynamic routes.

> If a page has Dynamic Routes and uses getStaticProps, it needs to define a list of paths to be statically generated.

from: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-paths